# ApexCharts Remove extra bottom padding

Tags: reactjs, charts, apexcharts

I have the following bar chart configuration.

```
const series = [
    {
      name: 'Net Profit',
      data: [18, 34, 55, 57, 80, 70],
    },
  ];
  const options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: '50px',
      toolbar: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
    grid: {
      show: false,
      padding: {
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
      },
      xaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: false,
        columnWidth: '80%',
        barHeight: '100%',
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    stroke: {
      show: false,
      width: 0,
      colors: ['transparent'],
    },
    fill: {
      opacity: 1,
      colors: [
        '#000000',
        '#B32824',
        '#1A73E8',
        '#B32824',
        '#1A73E8',
        '#B32824',
      ],
      type: 'solid',
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    xaxis: {
      axisTicks: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisBorder: {
        show: false,
      },
      labels: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
    yaxis: {
      axisTicks: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisBorder: {
        show: false,
      },
      labels: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
  };
```

I am getting extra padding at the bottom as below. how can I remove that?
[image]

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want to show x-axis and y-axis in your chart, you can simply do

```js
const options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: '250px',
    sparkline: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
}
```

The sparkline option will remove all paddings/margins around the chart.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue, and after reading the doc I found that you should set the value of `parentHeightOffset` as `0`, something like this

```
var opt1 = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      height: 200,
      ...
      parentHeightOffset: 0,
      ...
    },
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

sparkline option is great but if you still want a full chart, you need to update the grid's paddings:

```js
grid: {
  show: true,
  padding: { left: -10, right: -10, top: 0, bottom: 0 },
},
```